# How to load spring bean based on job we are running. Spring -batch

Tags: spring, spring-batch

We have common config file for multiple jobs and the for every job all the beans are loaded.I have to avoid this by loading the job related beans.Does any one knows ways to load only particular bean based on job

Comment: Could you please share some code ?

Comment: This might be helpful , we have 10 beans which gets loaded when we run any batch job.We have the same properties file for different jobs.I just want one bean in particular to not get loaded when I run a specif job.What kind of code you mean?